# How to access anonymous union/struct member in C++?

Tags: c++, anonymous-types

This question is my **mistake**.
The code described below is being built well with no problem.

---

I have this class.

**Vector.h**

```
struct  Vector
{
    union
    {
        float   elements[4];
        struct
        {
            float   x;
            float   y;
            float   z;
            float   w;
        };                  
    };

    float   length();
}
```

**Vector.cpp**

```
float Vector::length()
{
  return x;  // error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
}
```

How to access the member x,y,z,w?

Comment: This compiles fine for me (with a semicolon after struct Vector) in g++ 4.4.0. See http://ideone.com/m5tVu.

Comment: @TonyK I apology for my mistake. It's compiled well. I can't figure out why it was not compiled before... Sorry and thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an instance of your struct inside the anonymous union. I don't know exactly what you want to achive, but e.g. something like this would work:

```
struct Vector
{
  union
  {
    float elements[4];
    struct
    {
      float x, y, z, w;
    }aMember;
  };

  float length() const
  {
    return aMember.x;
  }
};
```

Comment: The error is occurring in a member function, where there's implicitly an instance.  I think this is probably due to something else.

Comment: @templatedtypedef: I was talking of the struct inside the union. And I updated my answer so please take away your downvote.

Comment: Cool, your answer seems more to the point of what OP wants. (and I learned something new today :o)) +1

Comment: The reason why you need a named member is that there are no anonymous structs in C++. `union { ... };` defines an unnamed type *and* an unnamed object, but `struct { ... };` defines *only* an unnamed type. I think the OP's code might even be illegal because the standard draft says that an anonymous union must not contain type declarations.

Comment: @Polybos, @Philipp I did want to know how to use those both of union & struct anonymously. I didn't know anonymous struct is illegal :) Because it was compiled in C with Clang. Thanks.

Comment: I'm kinda wondering.. I use anonymous structs for my math library as well, and there's no compiler error. `struct Vector3{ union{ struct{ float x; float y; float z; }; float a[3]; }; };` I can access x, y and z either directly by their name or with `a[0], a[1], a[2]`.

Comment: @Xeo Did you compile the source as C++? The code was compiled successfully as C, but not as C++ for me.

Comment: @Eonil My code compiled successfull as C++ – what compiler are you using?

Comment: Wow! It was compiled successfully as you mentioned! I apology for my mistake! I'm sorry again. It was really an error yesterday... I was used Clang.

Comment: @Eonil: Of course, I had class methods and everything. Just declared it as a struct so I don't need the `public` keyword.

Comment: @Xeo It was my mistake, it's compiling well now.. I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

What you have created is not an anonymous member, but anonymous type (which is useless by itself). You have to create a member of your anonymous type. This concerns both your struct and your union.

Adjust the header like this:

```
struct  Vector
{
    union
    {
        float   elements[4];
        struct
        {
            float   x;
            float   y;
            float   z;
            float   w;
        } v;
    } u;

    float   length();
};
```

Now you can access your members like this:

```
u.elements[0] = 0.5f;
if(u.v.x == 0.5f) // this will pass
    doStuff();
```

Comment: Why don't you want let him using anonymous unions? It's absolutely no problem and sometimes even recommended (http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12470)

Comment: @Polybos Good point, I didn't even know about anonymous unions until now :)